# Using "OR" operator in Java

Tags: java, string, while-loop, equals, logical-operators

This is the code.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter Product Code: ");
    medicine = machine1.nextInt();

    if (medicine==1) {
        machine1.buy1();
        machine1.addproduct(); 
    } 
    if (medicine==2); {
        machine1.buy2();
        machine1.addproduct();
    } 
} while((String answer=='y') || (String answer=='Y'));
```

And it gives this error:

> ```
> enter code    drugstore1.java:96: error: ')' expected
>             }while((String answer=='y'))||((String answer=='Y'));
>                                  ^    drugstore1.java:96: error: ';' expected
>             }while((String answer=='y'))||((String answer=='Y'));
>                                        ^  drugstore1.java:96: error: ';' expected
>             }while((String answer=='y'))||((String answer=='Y'));
>                                                           ^
> ```

It poof'ed after fixing other errors. I think I'm using it right.. But what is wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the line "while((String answer=='y'))||((String answer=='Y'))" ?

Comment: What do you think that code means?

Comment: `if(medicine==2);` <= You have an extra semi-colon which you need to remove.

Comment: It is for when a user wants to add an item or not. y or Y is for yes.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to write

```
while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
```

intead of

```
while((String answer=='y'))||((String answer=='Y'));
```

You cannot define new variables inside logical conditions.

```
1. String answer [X] -> answer [V]
2. answer=='y' [X] -> answer.equals("y") [V]
3. answer.equals("y") || answer.equals("Y") [V] -> answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y") [V]

4. if(medicine==2); [X] -> if (medicine == 2) [V]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `double quote` and `equalsignorecase` method in all you while condition like this:

```
  while(answer.equalsignorecase("y"));
```

Before try to use `nextLine()` when you want to insert string "y" with creating  variable:

```
  String answer= machine1.nextLine();
```

Like this:

```
  System.out.println("Enter Product Code: ");
    medicine = machine1.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter y if you want leave: ");
    String answer= machine1.nextLine();
```

Comment: @John see the additionale  answer

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm using... I've minimized it to 12 errors and now it's saying error: ";" expected whichis  pointing to the parenthesis next to my void.

Comment: @John if you want try to use this:while((String answer=='y')||(String answer=='Y')); you should remove the second parentesis

Answer (score 2):

Here are some guidelines:

- **Do not declare objects inside while() statements**. Did you mean `while(answer=="y")`?
- **Do not compare Strings using the == operator**. Strings are compared with `.equals()`. The `==` only checks if the two operands are at the same physical memory location.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to *declare* variables inside your condition:

```
String answer=='y'
```

How would a variable *declaration* be usable as a comparison?

Where *should* `answer` be coming from?  It doesn't exist anywhere in your code, so it's not clear at all what you're trying to accomplish there.

But once you *do* have an `answer` variable in your code which potentially contains some `'y'` or `'Y'` value, you can compare it like this:

```
while(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
```

---

Additionally, you have a bug here:

```
if(medicine==2);
```

That semi-colon is going to silently terminate the `if` block, and the following block of code will *always* execute regardless of the condition.  Remove that semi-colon.

Answer (score 2):

it should be

```
while("y".equalsIgnoreCase(answer)){// will avoid null pointer exception if answer is null

 if(medicine==1) 
            {
                machine1.buy1();
                machine1.addproduct(); 
            } 
        else if(medicine==2) // better for performance as both if conditions are mutually exclusive
            {
                machine1.buy2();
                machine1.addproduct();
            } 

}
```